# how to dislay the list by replacing the special symbol in kendo editor

Tags: angularjs, kendo-editor

I need to load the list of fields whenever the special character entered into kendo editor and replace the character by the field value.Here I mention my code

```
<textarea kendo-editor k-ng-model="trigger.message " calss = 'message' ng-change = viewList></textarea > 
                                       <ul>
                                          <li ng-repeat="option in data" ng-click="setData(option.field_name)">{{option.field_name}}</li>
                                       </ul>
```

in controller :

```
$scope.viewList = function() {

            var templist = []

            if ($scope.trigger.message == '' || $scope.trigger.message == undefined) {
                templist = [];
            } else if ($scope.trigger.message.indexOf('@') > -1) {
                templist = $scope.fields;
            }
            $scope.messageFields = templist;
        }

        $scope.setData = function(value) {
            $scope.trigger.message = $scope.trigger.message.replace('@', '') + " %" + value + "% ";
            $scope.messageFields = [];
        }
```

Anyone guides me to fix this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be as simple as wrapping your change event in quotes: `ng-change = viewList` to `ng-change = "viewList"`, otherwise it's going to break. Also, some more details around the problem you're facing, and some better formatting of your code would help substantially.

Comment: @omgaz thanks for your response I forget the to add quotes here.

Comment: Any one helps me to display the list in kendo editor based on replacing string.